# Execute arbitrary code in Corona

Tags: lua, execute, coronasdk

Is it possible to execute any arbitrary lua code in Corona? They've disabled loadfile, loadstring, and dofile. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason they've disabled it. Apple's restrictions don't allow it, so they took it out altogether for that reason. Not to mention it makes Corona more secure, I suppose.

Comment: What about Android? Or if we're not going to publish to apple's store?

Comment: You'll have to talk to Ansca about it. I'm just a Corona addict.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to enable the features you've mentioned with a Corona enterprise license (although that's relatively spendy if you're a small shop/independent developer.)